# Umbraco V6.1.3 Lucene Index Corruption

Tags: lucene, umbraco, umbraco6

Just upgraded an Umbraco V6.1.1 site to V6.1.3. All went well on my workstation. Copied the files up to the web server after deleting all that was there, did the same with the database. Set all the directory permissions and ran the site.  Site (which is MVC) runs BUT with two issues which I can't fathom and would really appreciate some help with.

One page errors with a Read Past EOF error. This is the view it's trying to run. The error is on link in Bold.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    Layout = "BasePage.cshtml";
}
          <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span12">
                  <h1>@Umbraco.Field("pageName")</h1>
                  @Umbraco.Field("pageText")
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="span12">
                @foreach (var page in Model.Content.Children) {
                    <section class="well">
                    <h3>@page.Name</h3>
                    @if(page.Children.Count() > 0) {
                        <ul>
                        **@foreach (var pub in page.Children) {**
                           <li><a href="@Umbraco.Media(pub.GetPropertyValue("publication")).Url" title="@pub.Name" target="_blank">@pub.Name</a></li>
                        }
                        </ul>
                    }
                    </section>
                }
                  </div>
          </div>
```

The Stack Trace is

```
[IOException: read past EOF]
   Lucene.Net.Index.FindSegmentsFile.Run(IndexCommit commit) +2040
   Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Open(Directory directory, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, IndexCommit commit, Boolean readOnly, Int32 termInfosIndexDivisor) +57
   Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher..ctor(Directory path, Boolean readOnly) +29
   Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneSearcher.ValidateSearcher(Boolean forceReopen) +136
```

The other (I think related issue) is in the CMS, when opening the Developer Section, I get a javascript alert with a huge error message in it relating to Lucene

```
error: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Could not create an index searcher with the supplied lucene directory","ExceptionType":"System.ApplicationException","StackTrace":"   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneSearcher.ValidateSearcher(Boolean forceReopen)\r\n   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneSearcher.GetSearcher()\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineExtensions.GetIndexReaderForSearcher(BaseLuceneSearcher searcher)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.Search.ExamineExtensions.GetIndexDocumentCount(LuceneIndexer indexer)\r\n   at Umbraco.Web.WebServices.ExamineManagementApiController.CreateModel(BaseIndexProvider indexer)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract.CreateWrapper(Object list)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClassd.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__c()\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)","InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"read past EOF","ExceptionType":"System.IO.IOException","StackTrace":"   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.FindSegmentsFile.Run(IndexCommit commit)\r\n   at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Open(Directory directory, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, IndexCommit commit, Boolean readOnly, Int32 termInfosIndexDivisor)\r\n   at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher..ctor(Directory path, Boolean readOnly)\r\n   at Examine.LuceneEngine.Providers.LuceneSearcher.ValidateSearcher(Boolean forceReopen)"}}}
```

Have tried the Umbraco forum but have had no replies. If it's a no-brainer, I still need to know of course.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd back up the indexes (they are in app_data\temp\....), and delete them and restart the app pool.

Umbraco will rebuild them (can take 5-10 mins for a HUGE database - 150k nodes) on next start up.

It might be a corrupt index (in which case, grab the backup and use Luke on it, see if it is broken), or possibly that the version of the index changed - which is the same result.

https://code.google.com/p/luke/

Comment: THANK YOU!  Deleting the contents of the TEMP/ExamineIndexes directory and restarting the app pool cleared both of the faults. That's a BIG weight off my mind :)

Comment: No problem. I'm running into similar problems with corrupt indexes :(

Comment: Fixed similar problem for me as well.