# Umbraco 7 macro script, get node by id fails

Tags: razor, umbraco7

i been trying to get a node by a id with razor in a marco
but can't get it to work with all the samples.

My code look like this

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
    var temp = Parameter.myFolderId;
    @temp;
    var node = @Library.NodeById(temp);

}
```

I got the temp's value, but i can't get the node.

i also tried it like this

> var node = @Model.NodeById(temp);

The only error Umbraco shows is

> Error loading MacroEngine script (file: myfile.cshtml)

I'm kinda new to Umbraco, so i could be a rookie mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

There was a problem with my indexes following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18130673/1866676)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking there shouldn't be a @ before Library.NodeById, since you're already inside a code block?

```
@{
    var temp = Parameter.myFolderId;
    var node = Library.NodeById(temp);
}
```

Comment: Hm. How about the new ContentService then? https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/management/services/contentservice